# How to save information separately form .txt into multiple strings in Java

Tags: java, filereader

I have a mydata.txt, where I want to read in information separately.

The 1st row save as "zoo number", "animal number"

the 2nd row till the 5th row save as "data for animals in matrix"

the 6th row save as dog "number" "appetite" "weight" "height"

```
2 83
30 50 21 42 0 3 
55 56 78 34 2 1
87 76 23 21 3 2
88 22 56 78 32 8
dog 23 79 67 21
```

The code I written as below, however, my code only be able to reload everything form mydata.txt into a string. But I want to save those information separately into individual string (for that matrix) and variables (E.g. dog's number, dog's sappetite...) . How can I do that?

```
 private void readFile(String fileName){

        try{

            File file = new File("myData.txt");
            FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
            StringBuffer stringBuffer=new StringBuffer();   

            String line = bufferedReader.readLine();

            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)  {
                stringBuffer.append(line);     
                stringBuffer.append("\n");  
            }

            fileReader.close();
            bufferedReader.close();

            System.out.println("Contents of File: ");
            System.out.println(stringBuffer.toString());  

        }catch (IOException e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

Comment: You will have to parse the `String` read by the reader accordingly, e.g. by splitting the read line on the whitespaces. But since each line contains different data, the task is not as trivial.  Additionally, the code you posted contains an infinite loop. The `while (line != null)` will loop forever, since `line` is not reassigned in the loop body. Should be `while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)`.

Comment: @maloomeister Thank you for replying. Just fix. Would you mind giving me a sample code to be more straightforward in understanding?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you should use `split` method from String class.

```
  String[] rowOne = line.split(" ");
  int zooNumber = Integer.valueOf(rowOne[0]);
  int animalNumber = Integer.valueOf(rowOne[1]);
```

So when you split with `" "` will give you array for String splitted by spaces. Then reading Index by Index will give you desired values.

**Updated Answer:** You can get value row by row as below :

```
int i = 1;

      while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {

        if (i == 1) {
          String[] rowOne = line.split(" ");
          int zooNumber = Integer.valueOf(rowOne[0]);
          int animalNumber = Integer.valueOf(rowOne[1]);
        } else if(i > 1 && i < 6) {
          String[] midRows = line.split(" ");
          // retrieve values at index 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ,5
          // First 2nd Row
          // Index 0 : 30
          // Index 1 : 50
          //,...
        } else if(i == 6) {
          String[] midRows = line.split(" ");
          // retrieve values at index 0, 1, 2, 3, 4
          // First 6th Row
          // Index 0 : dog
          // Index 1 : 23
          //,...
        } else {
          break;
        }
        i++;
      }
```

Comment: Thank you for replying. Here I save the file's contents inside ```stringBuffer.toString()```. How should I link with your comments then? As ````String[] rowOne```` does not connect with my read data so far. ```dataRead = stringBuffer.toString(); ```

Comment: Here you are doing string concat. Rather you should read it one line at a time as you have fixed number of lines. And skip using this StringBuffer

Comment: And just a point out of this StringBuffer should be replaced with StringBuilder here, as StringBuffer will make execution slower

Comment: That's a fantastic suggestion! Thank you so much! Is there a better way to read the matrix? How about write a for-loop to read that matrix? As read one element by one element is not efficient.

Comment: Yes you can maintain the index. So if Index is 1 : Then so something, if 2 to 5 do something else, and if 6 do something else. Like wise

Comment: Hi, thank you. I tried to read the 2rd row by writing ```String[] rowTwo = line.split(" ");
  int maxtrixRow1Col1= Integer.valueOf(rowTwo[0]);```,  This gives me a wrong number (the number the same as rowOne[1] ). And I misuderstand how to read row by row here?

Comment: @Scarlett Please check my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You could setup your myData.txt file like so: 
zoo_number 2, animal_number 83 
key1 30, key2 50...
...
animal dog, dog_appetite 23,...

Then what you do is iterate through every line like so:

```
    import java.util.*;

    import java.io.*;

    public class App{
      public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
        File file = new File("myData.txt");
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(file);
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(fileReader);

        Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

        while(sc.hasNextLine()){
          String[] inputText = sc.nextLine().trim().split(",");
          for(String sentence : inputText){//every key_Value pair in a line
            String key = sentence.split(" ")[0];//key, value in key_value pair
            String value = sentence.split(" ")[1];
            map.put(key, value);
          }
      }

      System.out.println(map);

      sc.close();
  }
}
```

output:{key1=30, key2=50, number=23, zooNumber=2, animal=dog, animal=83}

**KEEP IN MIND MAP DOES NOT ACCEPT DUPLICATE KEYS**